# Iterate thorugh a particular column of pandas Dataframe/Series

Tags: python, pandas, countvectorizer

I am implementing a research paper in which i have to categorize a cuisine based on its ingredients. Ingredients training data-set and test data-set is provided. Everything working fine. Model has been trained using best approach according to accuracy among SGD, RandomForest & Naive Bayes. I am using Random Forest because its accuracy is better than both of NB and SGD. Testing data-set is tested and prediction is working absolutely fine. Now i want to predict cuisine by manually inputting ( using `input()` of python ) ingredients. Here the problem comes when i try to search in series/Dataframe of pandas named here `Y = train_data['all_ingredients'] OR Y = train_data['ingredients']`.

```
def check_ing(ing):
    if ing in train_data['all_ingredients'].values:
        return True
    return False


no_of_ingredients = input("Total Number Of Ingredients: ")
no_of_ingredients = int(no_of_ingredients)
ingredient = []
for i in range(no_of_ingredients):
    ing = input("Enter Ingredient " + str(i) + " : ")
    if check_ing(ing) is True:
        ingredient.append(ing)

print(ingredient)
```

The problem is in the if statement of function `check_ing(ing)`.
How to improve that to search ingredient entered by user that if it is valid or not.

Result of `Y.head()` is:
[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. There's a lot of back-story about training methods, but your question appears to be to "improve on this" when we don't really know the issue in the first place

Comment: I just added the background to be sure.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit it out - I think it's distracting tbh. But I can't gather the crux of the question so I don't want to leave it without a distinct point that you're trying to solve

Comment: Distinct point is that if statement in function `check_ing(ing)` as i stated. How can i improve that to search through the whole `train_data['ingredients']` for example if user enters `garlic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answers your question, if the input is not in the column ingredients, it will be invalid, you might have to alter the first part of the if

EDIT: didn't test it, this should work.
EDIT 2: messed up copying and pasting.

```
all_ing = [item for sublist in train_data["Ingredients"] for item in sublist]

def check_ing(ing):
    if ing in all_ing:
            return True
    else:
        print("invalid ingredient")
        return False 

no_of_ingredients = input("Total Number Of Ingredients: ")
no_of_ingredients = int(no_of_ingredients)
ingredient = []

for i in range(no_of_ingredients):
    ing = input("Enter Ingredient " + str(i) + " : ")
    tf = check_ing(ing)
    if tf is True:
        ingredient.append(ing)

print(ingredient)
```

Comment: It isn't coming inside the `if statement` and giving invalid ingredient on even valid ones.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but one thing you could improve is use `set` instead of `Series`:

```
valid_ing = set(train_data['Ingredients'])

def check_ing(ing):
    return  ing in valid_ing
```

Test sample:

```
d = [''.join(np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijklmn'), 10, replace=True)) for _ in range(1000)]
s = pd.Series(d)

%%timeit
'abc' in s
# 4.3 µs ± 365 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

valid_ing  = set(s)
%%timeit
'abc' in valid_ing 
# 155 ns ± 15.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```